# Will Ubuntu Server properly manage the power settings on a netbook?

Tags: 10.10, server, ubuntu-netbook, laptop, power-management

I'm planning to install Ubuntu Server on a netbook to minimize power consumption.

Are there any special considerations I should make for this kind of setup? Will Ubuntu Server properly manage the laptop's power settings and CPU scaling by default, or will I need to make changes to the configuration or install packages that would normally only be found in Ubuntu Desktop?

Comment: If you really want to save power, it's probably better & cheaper to use something like a [plugcomputer](http://plugcomputer.org/) (unless you already have the netbook of course).

Comment: I'm hoping to snag a netbook with a smashed LCD for cheap, but you're right, a plugcomputer would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CPU scaling will work as expected, this is part of the core OS that isn't different between Desktop and Server. If you want things like suspend-on-lid-close to work, though, you may need have some of the Gnome stack running to gain *gnome-power-manager*.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your netbook as server, then you can install ubuntu-server, but if you want to install a server-dedicated system to make some economy on resources usage then simply install xubuntu or zenwalk (a slackware based system)